# opensearch single field, string_query only find document when a random field is added to the field list

Tags: field, query-string, opensearch

I have a very weird situation with opensearch...

This document:

```
{
   name: 'Andrew Jones',
   contact_name: nil,
   address_nil,
   account_id: 1234
}
```

is NOT searchable with this query

```
{:bool=>
  {:should=>
    [{:query_string=>
       {:query=>"andrew jones",
        :fields=>["name"],
        :type=>:best_fields,
        :allow_leading_wildcard=>true,
        :default_operator=>"AND",
        :minimum_should_match=>1}}],
   :minimum_should_match=>1,
   :filter=>[{:term=>{:account_id=>1234}}]}}
```

but if I add the contact_name or the address into fhe fields list, then it is searchable, the above query will find the record if it is written as...

```
{:bool=>
  {:should=>
    [{:query_string=>
       {:query=>"andrew jones",
        :fields=>["name", "contact_name"],
        :type=>:best_fields,
        :allow_leading_wildcard=>true,
        :default_operator=>"AND",
        :minimum_should_match=>1}}],
   :minimum_should_match=>1,
   :filter=>[{:term=>{:account_id=>1234}}]}}
```

Could anyone please advise what could be the issue?, name is a edge-ngram field
this is the settings of that index

```
{"customers"=>
  {"settings"=>
    {"index"=>
      {"replication"=>{"type"=>"DOCUMENT"},
       "refresh_interval"=>"60s",
       "number_of_shards"=>"1",
       "provided_name"=>"customers",
       "creation_date"=>"1701847737857",
       "analysis"=>
        {"filter"=>
          {"edge_ngram_filter"=>
            {"type"=>"edge_ngram", "min_gram"=>"1", "max_gram"=>"20"}},
         "analyzer"=>
          {"autocomplete"=>
            {"filter"=>["lowercase", "edge_ngram_filter"],
             "type"=>"custom",
             "tokenizer"=>"standard"}}},
       "number_of_replicas"=>"2",
       "uuid"=>"xxxxxxxxx",
       "version"=>{"created"=>"136327827"}}}}}
```

i tried "explain" and the result is:

```
{"_index"=>"customers",
 "_id"=>"477323",
 "matched"=>false,
 "explanation"=>
  {"value"=>0.0,
   "description"=>
    "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
   "details"=>
    [{"value"=>0.0,
      "description"=>
       "no match on required clause ((+name:andrew +name:jones)~1)",
      "details"=>
       [{"value"=>0.0,
         "description"=>
          "Failure to match minimum number of optional clauses: 1",
         "details"=>
          [{"value"=>11.455513,
            "description"=>
             "weight(name:andrew in 669578) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
            "details"=>
             [{"value"=>11.455513,
               "description"=>
                "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
               "details"=>
                [{"value"=>2.2, "description"=>"boost", "details"=>[]},
                 {"value"=>7.5547304,
                  "description"=>
                   "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details"=>
                   [{"value"=>5382,
                     "description"=>"n, number of documents containing term",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>10279256,
                     "description"=>"N, total number of documents with field",
                     "details"=>[]}]},
                 {"value"=>0.6892438,
                  "description"=>
                   "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                  "details"=>
                   [{"value"=>1.0,
                     "description"=>
                      "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>1.2,
                     "description"=>"k1, term saturation parameter",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>0.75,
                     "description"=>"b, length normalization parameter",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>2.0,
                     "description"=>"dl, length of field",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>11.9311695,
                     "description"=>"avgdl, average length of field",
                     "details"=>[]}]}]}]},
           {"value"=>8.6221695,
            "description"=>
             "weight(name:jones in 669578) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
            "details"=>
             [{"value"=>8.6221695,
               "description"=>
                "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
               "details"=>
                [{"value"=>2.2, "description"=>"boost", "details"=>[]},
                 {"value"=>5.686185,
                  "description"=>
                   "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details"=>
                   [{"value"=>34872,
                     "description"=>"n, number of documents containing term",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>10279256,
                     "description"=>"N, total number of documents with field",
                     "details"=>[]}]},
                 {"value"=>0.6892438,
                  "description"=>
                   "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                  "details"=>
                   [{"value"=>1.0,
                     "description"=>
                      "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>1.2,
                     "description"=>"k1, term saturation parameter",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>0.75,
                     "description"=>"b, length normalization parameter",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>2.0,
                     "description"=>"dl, length of field",
                     "details"=>[]},
                    {"value"=>11.9311695,
                     "description"=>"avgdl, average length of field",
                     "details"=>[]}]}]}]}]}]},
     {"value"=>0.0,
      "description"=>"match on required clause, product of:",
      "details"=>
       [{"value"=>0.0, "description"=>"# clause", "details"=>[]},
        {"value"=>1.0,
         "description"=>"account_id:[1234 TO 1234]",
         "details"=>[]}]}]}}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't think so it's related to `contact_name` field because the value is `nil`. It can be related to `refresh_interval`. refresh_interval is set to 60s that means the indexed data will be available for search after 60 seconds. For testing,  create a new index, send query request to only `name` field, wait 1 minute, send the same query again.

Comment: Hi Musab,

Thank you for your reply, the record has been in the index for some time, as you can see, I can search the record using the second query, if I use the first query now, it still cannot find it.

Comment: You're welcome can you share `GET customers/_doc/477323`